# For memoir class, just what does "typeblock" include.

Tags: margins, memoir

The documentation `memman.pdf` for the memoir document class describes in Section 2.4 how to lay out the *typeblock.* But it never defines that term.

Exactly what does the typeblock encompass?

1. In its height, does it include the headers and footers?
2. In its width, does it include marginal notes?

It seems that "typeblock" there does *not* mean what is usually called the "text body" (or simply "body"), because the documentation uses the separate term *textblock* for that.

I need the clarification in order to intelligently set up the parameters for page layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is best answered in Section 2.1 (Laying out the page / Introduction). I'll quote the paragraph here:

> There are three main parts to a page: the page itself, the typeblock,
>   and the margins separating the typeblock from the edges of the page.
>   Of slightly lesser importance are the running headers and footers, and
>   possibly marginal notes. The art of page design is obtaining a
>   harmonious balance or rhythm between all these.

In other words, the typeblock is the rectangle inside which all the body of the document is contained. It does *not* include running headers and footers, nor margin-, side-, and footnotes.

It may also help you to read [Peter Wilson's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12082/peter-wilson) excellent companion book, [A Few Notes on Book Design](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/memdesign/memdesign.pdf), especially section 3.2. Again, I quote:

> A page in a book will typically contain several elements. *Principal
>   among these* is the **typeblock**, *but there are also items* like the **folio**
>   (that is, the page number), a **running header and/or footer** which
>   carries the chapter and/or book title, and possibly **marginalia** and
>   **footnotes.** These latter elements, although essential to the content of
>   the book, are minor visual elements compared to the typeblock.

Comment: That documentation still does not explicitly say that the headers & footers and marginal nots are *not* part of the "typeblock". Nor does it either distinguish between "textblock" and "typeblock" or identify the two as being the same thing. That's why I asked! I had examined Peter Wilson's "A Few Notes...", and that doesn't totally clarify the issue either.

Comment: I've added another quote, from AFNOBD 3.2; I hope my markup helps in interpreting it.

Comment: Nope, that added quote still does not actually answer what I've asked!

Comment: It certainly doesn't help that in the _really_ old days, the type block refers to the block on which the individual letters sit.

Comment: I think the phrase type block is used interchangeably with "text body", as Brent's answer suggests. Evidence: on page 16 of the memoir manual the command `\settypeblocksize` is used to set `\textwidth` and `\textheight`, which would suggest that the width and the height of the typeblock is exactly that of the text body.

Comment: There's a slight additional confusion, in that Peter Wilson uses the phrases "typeblock", "textblock", and "text block" in ways that seem, occasionally, contradictory (especially WRT footnotes).

Comment: I've just sent Peter an email inviting him to comment...

Answer (score 4):

I must obviously apologise for the poor documentation of `memoir` even though this is the first time this question has been asked over the last 15 years. Brent Longborough has already answered your question but if you look at Figures 2.2, 2.2 and 2.3 in the manual then the rectangle there that is labelled 'Body' is the typeblock. It does not include headers, footers, marginal notes, merely the running text (including chapter/section etc. headings plus any footnotes). Page headers and footers (e.g., page numbers) are external to the typeblock.

Comment: *Fons et origo*

Comment: the `memoir` documentation is hardly "poor". Sometimes it takes a lot of reading through the details to put things together. My question was for clarification of one little ambiguity. Thanks for your response -- and for the package itself!